# Does $ \frac{F}{a} = \rho V $?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, density

We have two equations:
$$ F = ma $$
and
$$ \rho = \dfrac{m}{V} $$
where $F = $ force, $m = $ mass, $a $ = acceleration, $\rho = $ density, and $V $ = volume.

Rearrange the equations:
$$ m = \dfrac{F}{a} $$
and
$$ m = \rho V $$

Then, shouldn't
$$ \dfrac{F}{a} = \rho V $$?

This sounds odd though, relating force and acceleration with density and volume. What is wrong with this math, and if it is actually correct, how are these things related? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For an object of uniform density (which is the only sort of object $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$ applies to), and taking $F$ to be net force (so I will use $F_{\text{net}}$ instead), this is correct. It's just not particularly interesting. These two equations usually apply to different situations; $F = ma$ is typically used when considering the whole object in motion, whereas $\rho = \frac{m}{V}$ is often used to describe a part of the object which is typically not in motion.

If you ever do encounter a situation where $\frac{F_{\text{net}}}{a} = \rho V$ would be useful, you can get the same results by just calculating the mass from one equation and plugging it into the other. If there is some insight to be gained in some particular situation by combining the equations and manipulating them together, I can't think of it.